# ASP.NET form field already have data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 methods(actions) to create new "racun". Difference is, 1st one has dropdown list to choos kupac_id(FK),and the 2nd already has kupac_id sent by GET method. First one looks like this:

```
 // GET: racuns/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.kupac_id = new SelectList(db.kupacs, "id_kupac", "naziv");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: racuns/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_racun,dv_racuna,status,dv_placanja,kupac_id")] racun racun)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.racuns.Add(racun);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.kupac_id = new SelectList(db.kupacs, "id_kupac", "naziv", racun.kupac_id);
        return View(racun);
    }
```

And the other one is like this:

```
// GET: racuns/CreateZaKupca
    public ActionResult CreateZaKupca(int vid)
    {
        return View(new racun { kupac_id = vid });
    }

    // POST: racuns/CreateZaKupca
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateZaKupca([Bind(Include = "id_racun,dv_racuna,status,dv_placanja,kupac_id")] racun racun)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.racuns.Add(racun);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(racun);
    }
```

So, when I run 1st action i got this -> http://prntscr.com/9k2cmc 
And 2nd -> http://prntscr.com/9k2e56 
Why is that, and can i get rid of those number and have empty field like in 1st action?
Ty for any help. EDIT:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dv_racuna, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dv_racuna, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dv_racuna, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Part of code from view.

Comment: What are you binding that field to in your view?

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your question. But guess that this part of code (i'll put it in my question) could tell you something. Thx for your attention.

Comment: Based on the code currently in the question, it would seem reasonable that the `dv_racuna` property on the model contains a `DateTime` value (or something visually similar) which is being displayed.

Comment: Yeah, i made database in managament studio, and it is smalldatetime. Also its NOT NULL. http://prntscr.com/9k2nij But i dont understand why is in 2nd action field already filed with some date, and in 1st one not, and could i remove that date from 2nd action,

Comment: Hard to say from the code shown why the two would behave differently.  The different action names suggest that there are two views.  If that's the case, maybe there's a difference in the code for those fields in the views?  You might also place debugging breakpoints on the `return View(racun);` lines and inspect the models being sent to each view to see if there's a difference.  That might help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: I was checked, this part of code is same in both view. I'm learging ASP.NET so i was wondering if someone could tell me whats the problem. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second action method, you are passing an object of your `racun`  view model to the view and i am assuming that you have a property in this view model of type `DateTime`.

```
public class racun 
{
  public DateTime Datum_Racuna {set;get;}
}
```

And in your view, something like

```
@model racun
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.EditorFor(s=>s.Datum_Racuna)
}
```

If you do not set the value of this property to a valid datetime, It will return you the `DateTime.MinValue` value(`1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`), which is what you see in the form field.

If you wish to avoid this behaviour, you may change your property type from `DateTime` to Nullable DateTime(`DateTime?`).

```
public class racun 
{
  public DateTime? Datum_Racuna {set;get;}
}
```

Now since you changed the property type to nullable, you should do a null check before accessing the value to avoid Null Reference exceptions.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(racun model)
{
  if(model.Datum_Racuna!=null) 
  {
    var dtValue=model.Datum_Racuna.Value;
  }
  // to do :do something useful and return something useful.
}
```

Comment: Thx, o7, i was thinking, could it be becouse of NOT NULL, but didnt want to say something stupid :)